# Why do we pop the dollar symbol when it's already present in the stack in PDA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

Could anyone tell the reason for popping the top of stack(dollar symbol) as said in this [lecture](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=66031715C5F84356!660&authkey=!AOq3YLlkKKfswak&ithint=file%2cpdf)(p.54) when there's already dollar symbol in the stack.

I would like to know if we could replace the transition given [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=66031715C5F84356!660&authkey=!AOq3YLlkKKfswak&ithint=file%2cpdf)(p.54) of the form

A,`$` $\to$ 0`$`

with

A,$\epsilon \to$ 0.

Comment: 1) That's no article. 2) What exactly do they say?

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "end-of-stack" symbol (often $\$$) is necessary for the automaton to know when there are no more stack symbols. Therefore, when we reach $\$$ we have two options:

1. Remove the $\$$ and terminate¹.
2. Put it back there for later, maybe adding additional symbols.

Ergo, as long as you do not want to terminate you have to keep putting $\$$ back when you find it.

*Why* does it have ot be like that, you ask? In the definition I know, PDAs always "take out"² the top-most symbol. So the creator of the PDA has no choice but to deal with the $\$$ once it is on the top of the stack.

But *why* define it like that, you ask? If PDAs were allowed to not consume the topmost stack symbol they'd be inherently nondeterministic. And since you gain nothing by this choice -- doing nothing with the stack is trivial to simulate by just putting the symbol you read back -- there is no reason to introduce this source of nondeterminism.

---

1. Depending on the definition, termination is *defined* by empty stack or you have to switch into a final state. The definitions are equivalent.
2. Remember that it's an declarative, not an algorithmic definition!

Comment: :Could you tell why PDAs would be inherently nondeterministic if they weren't allowed to consume the topmost stack symbol.

Comment: I think it's self-evident. Please do some thinking on your own; I won't reply anymore unless you have a specific question resp. proposal about my answer. [Several comments deleted.]

Comment: :I meant to say the transition as given [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs121/fall12/lecnotes/PDAvsCFG.pdf)(p.4).While in the post they have merged the first and second last transition in this [lecture](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs121/fall12/lecnotes/PDAvsCFG.pdf)(p.4) to get the transition in the post.I hope you understand this comment.