# Why can you push multiple symbols on a PDA stack at once?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I'm really new to learning about PDA's and stuff, i understand that on a edge between 2 nodes you'll have something like this a,b->c. This means:

if a is in the beginning of your string and b is on top of your stack you can

- remove a from your string (the one you run through the PDA),
- remove b from your stack
- place c on your stack

and take the edge...

My book also tells me that you can place more then one symbols on your stack. For instance a,b->cd.

I think this is because you can also have this edge  ε, ε -> c wich just puts c on the top of the stack,

so a,b->cd between Node 1 and 2 can by replaced by Node1 - a,b->c - New node -  ε, ε->d -> Node2.
Can someone please confirm if this is correct?

the pda is defined as (Q,E,T,d,s,F) with

- Q an finite collection of states
- E a finite inputalfabet
- T a finite stackalfabet
- d a transitionfunction Q x E (including ε) x T (including ε) -> V collection of(Q x T (including ε))
- s the startstate
- F a collection of eindstates (subcollection of Q)

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always [have to take out a symbol](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55165/98). So if we could only write a single symbol, we could never really build up stack content.

Writing more than two symbols is just syntactic sugar; we could easily simulate it with PDAs restricted to writing zero, one, or two symbols.

Comment: thanks for the help, but you don't always have to take out a symbol, you can take the empty string from your string or stack wich leaves them unchanged... ( ε, ε -> d just puts d on the stack regardless of the current first symbol in your string, symbol at top of stack)

Comment: i was thinking that because of this a,b -> cd could always be changed by a,b->c in the first edge (E1) followed directly by  ε, ε->d in the next one (E2), but i'm not sure if this is correct so from N1 - Edge (a,b->cd) - N2 would become N1 - E1 - NewNode - E2- N2

Comment: or is that what you meant with "simulate it with PDAs ..." :p

Comment: @FOKDIEKUL Be careful not to have things backwards. You "can have" certain constellations because the definitions permits them, not the other way around. The motivations behind defintions usually go deeper, and may be missing from introductory textbooks.